# Regexp: How to find and replace brackets around numbers in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to do a regex replace operation in notepad++

here is the test string:

```
td{2}(i,j),
td{3}(i,j),
td{4}(i,j),
```

And I would like to end up with this:

```
td(2,i,j),
td(3,i,j),
td(4,i,j),
```

I can find the string, but I don't know how to write the replacement string.

```
\{\d{1}\}\(
```

I tried the above expression with (.)$ to find the number

```
\{\d{1}\}\(
```

and this for the replacement string but it didn't work

```
 \($1,
```

How can I get the results I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\{(\d)}(\()
```

Replace with `$2$1,`. Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Bh1Fh/1). *Details*:

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `(\d)` (or `(\d+)` to match more than one digit) - Group 1 (`$1`): a digit
- `}` - a `}` char
- `(\()` - Group 2 (`$2`): a `(` char.

The replacement is a concatenation of Group 2 (the `(` char) + Group 1 (the digit(s)) + `,`. If you do not capture `(` into Group 2 (i.e. if you use `\{(\d)}\(` or `\{(\d+)}\(`), you could use the `\($1,` replacement, where `(` needs escaping.

See the demo screenshot with settings:

[image]